# Angular4 with Angular Google Maps (AGM) - display markers with loop *ngFor

Tags: angular, google-maps, firebase

Please it's been 2 weeks that I block on my code.

I use Angular4 with Firebase and Angular Google Maps (AGM)
https://angular-maps.com/guides/getting-started/

I'm trying to display markers with loop *ngFor but I can not do it

result with angular4 + firebase

[image]

```
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="1">

  <agm-marker *ngFor="let cavist of cavists;" [latitude]="cavist.lat" [longitude]="cavist.lng">
          <agm-info-window>
            <strong>{{cavist.title}}</strong>
            <br>
            <br><img src="{{cavist.imageUrl}}" alt="{{cavist.title}}">
            <br>
            <br><strong>adresse</strong>
            <br><span>{{cavist.adress}}</span>
            <br><span>{{cavist.zipcode}} - {{cavist.city}}</span>
            <br>
            <br><strong>description</strong>
            <br><span>{{cavist.description}}</span>
            <br>
            <br><strong>coordonnees gps</strong>
            <br><span>latitude: {{cavist.lat}}</span>
            <br><span>longitude: {{cavist.lng}}</span>
            <br>
          </agm-info-window>    
        </agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

However, I managed without difficulty with Angular 4 but without firebase.

result with angular4

[image]

Please can you help me?

Comment: Are you still encountering this? Is it possible for you to post your code in a a [minimum, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Since you're using angular, maybe a site like [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) would help you show the issue so we can reproduce it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! No, I just solved the problem right now. It was just a problem of string fields instead of number for lat & lng.